# Am i able to remarry my ex husband after getting a fasagh after being separated for 3 yearsbut he never gave me 3 talqs

Tags: halal-haram, hadith, sharia, talaq, husband-wife

My ex husband and I was separated for 3 years before I went for my fasagh. I went under Idaho however,he only gave me 1 talaq in the time we were together.  We are older and a bit wiser now and want to remarry, is this permissible in Islam?